# Flatten glob down to one directory

Tags: node.js, gulp

Within Gulp, I am using `gulp.src` to select every font file from a directory:

```
gulp.task('copy-fonts', function() {
   gulp.src('components/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}')
   .pipe(gulp.dest('build/fonts'));
});
```

However, I would like to have all of these font files wind up in one directory side-by-side rather than have the entire tree re-created from the `components` directory.

Looking in the Gulp, Gulp Utils, and npm-glob APIs didn't really help me, though I could've easily skipped by it.

What would the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I would use gulp-flatten:

```
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');
gulp.task('copy-fonts', function() {
  gulp.src('dependencies/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}')
  .pipe(flatten())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('build/fonts'));
});
```

As to how this is done internally, check: https://github.com/armed/gulp-flatten/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Wow! I guess I wasn't searching hard enough. The example in the NPM is pretty much exactly my use case.

Comment: I would suggest getting through most entries here to get a good idea of what's possible with plugins: http://gratimax.github.io/search-gulp-plugins/ - it's also a good way to learn how to roll your own from reading source there!

Comment: @MangledDeutz the link is broken

Comment: This worked awesome for harvesting all the .scss from my ionic component library to import into the application .

Answer (score 20):

Another option is to simply rewrite the file path inside `gulp.dest`:

```
var path = require('path');
gulp.task('copy-fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src('components/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file) {
            file.path = file.base + path.basename(file.path);
            return 'build/fonts';
        }));
});
```

You can also use this technique with `gulp-changed`:

```
var path = require('path');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');

gulp.task('copy-fonts', function() {
  var dest = 'build/fonts';
  return gulp.src('components/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}')
    .pipe(changed(function(file) {
      file.path = file.base + path.basename(file.path);
      return dest;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```

Comment: Underrated answer

Comment: This almost worked for me, but I had to add separator: `file.path = path.join(file.base, path.basename(file.path));`

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the glob library to unglob your paths, and then pass the file paths into gulp.src. When gulp src receives unglobbed file paths the relative dir is not maintained and simply copies the file to the root of the dest dir you specify. It can also be useful to unglob your paths first if you need to do any custom filtering or appending before setting src.

```
glob = require('glob');
gulp.task('copy-fonts', function() {
  files = glob.sync('dependencies/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}');

  gulp.src(files)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/fonts'));
});
```