# Use gulp to select and move directories and their files

Tags: node.js, glob, gulp

I'm currently using gulp to call a bash script that cleans my `dist/` directory and moves the appropriate files to the clean directory. I would like this to be done with gulp because I am not sure the script would work on a non *nix file system.
So far, I'm using the gulp-clean module to clean the `dist/` directory but when I try to move the required directories and their files to the dist folder, the directories are empty.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean');

gulp.task('clean', function(){
  return gulp.src(['dist/*'], {read:false})
  .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('move',['clean'], function(){
  gulp.src(['_locales', 'icons', 'src/page_action', 'manifest.json'])
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('dist', ['move']);
```

calling `gulp dist` results in the the `dist/` directory being populated with the correct directories but they are all empty

```
$ ls dist/*
dist/manifest.json

dist/_locales:

dist/icons:

dist/page_action:
```

How do I copy the directories and their contents to the `dist/` folder?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You need to include the [`base` option](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src#options) to src, which will preserve the file structure the way you want:

```js
var filesToMove = [
        './_locales/**/*.*',
        './icons/**/*.*',
        './src/page_action/**/*.*',
        './manifest.json'
    ];

gulp.task('move',['clean'], function(){
  // the base option sets the relative root for the set of files,
  // preserving the folder structure
  gulp.src(filesToMove, { base: './' })
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

---

Also, you are probably going to have trouble down the road if you have all these source files in the root of your project.

**If** you can, I'd recommend you use a single `src/` folder and move *all* your application-specific files into there.  This makes maintenance easier moving forward, and prevents your build-specific files from getting mixed up with your application-specific files.

If you do this, then simply replace all occurrences of `./` with `src/` in the example above.

Comment: Worked perfectly only after reorganizing the files but your reasoning is sound so I'm marking your answer as correct. Thank you.

Comment: To do the opposite, use gulp-flatten. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153338/flatten-glob-down-to-one-directory?rq=1

Comment: As a note for anyone else who did this, make sure you don't have the `read` option in src set to `false` (it's set to `true` by default).

Comment: When I do this, it is copying with the whole root directories.

Answer (score 6):

The original question targets only **directories**  (a.k.a. folders) in its `gulp.src`, i.e. `gulp.src(['_locales', ...` in this example, `_locales` is the name of a **directory**.

The accepted answer uses a [`glob` pattern](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob)  in its `gulp.src` to target **files** anywhere in those directories, i.e. `gulp.src(['./_locales/**/*.*', ...`, (notice the *double-asterisks*, and the *filename.extension* asterisks). The accepted answer works...

...*but the accepted answer only emphasizes the `base` option*:

> You need to include the **`base` option** to src...

I experimented and found:

1. Strictly speaking, it is unnecessary to use the `base` option to achieve what the OP asked:  "...and moves the appropriate **files** to the clean directory." The `base` option *does* indeed preserve the *folder+file* **structure** (as described in the accepted answer), but the `base` option is **not sufficient** to move the files as the OP **asked**. Preserving the folder+file structure is probably what the OP **expects**, so the accepted answer is good, but...
2. Just to reiterate what **does** move the files, it's the `glob` patterns:

   1. Double-asterisk (`.../**/...`) searches recursively throughout all subfolders, and subfolders' subfolders', etc.
   2. Filename.extension asterisks (`.../*.*`) finds **files** of all *names*, and all *extensions*. **So I think this part deserves the most emphasis!**
3. The accepted answer changes something else; it adds a prefix of `./` to each path arguments passed to `gulp.src`. I think that's unnecessary/redundant; if there is no `./`, (as in the OP question), the paths are resolved relative to the current directory -- *resulting in the same behavior*. But maybe it's good practice to be explicit with the `./`

Let me know if I'm mistaken...

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I didn't need the `base` option but I needed to specify the `*.*` exactly as you described to actually move the correct files. +1