# Move files from differend folders to ONE folder. Without subfolders. Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, glob

I need some help.

How to move files from different folders to ONE folder, without subfolders in Gulp?

For example my project structure:

```
build/
   js/
source/
   /modules
      /list
         - list.js
      /editor
         - editor.js
      /menu
         - menu.js
```

I need to move all js files from source to build/js:

```
build/
   /js
      - list.js
      - editor.js
      - menu.js
```

I have code:

```
gulp.task('build-partials', function(){
    gulp.src('source/modules/*/*.js', {base: 'source/modules/'})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'))
});
```

But in build/js/ i see this:

```
build/
   /js
      /list
         - list.js
      /editor
         - editor.js
      /menu
         - menu.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using gulp-flatten

```
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  gulp.src(['source/modules/**/*'])
    .pipe(flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gulp-nosubfolders: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nosubfolders

```
var nosubfolders = require('gulp-nosubfolders');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp
           .src('./js/**')
           .pipe(nosubfolders())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./my/dest/path'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `gulp-concat` instead. Your code will look something like this:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  // List all source files in array
  return gulp.src(['source/modules/*/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'));
});
```

Read more on the [NPM module page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat).

Comment: Sorry. It's not a sollution. I can't concat all files to one. I just want to move it.

Comment: Maybe try this then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546931/use-gulp-to-select-and-move-directories-and-their-files