# How to move files using gulp task?

Tags: gulp

I have the folder structure like below.

```
--projects
   --project1
      --dist
      --src
        --.js files
   --project2
      --dist
      --src
        --.js files
   ---
```

I tried to move the js files from src to dist using gulp task.

```
gulp.task('move', function () {    
    gulp.src('./projects/**/src/*.js', {base: './projects/'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest("/dist"));     
});
```

But it doesn't copy from src to dist. How to move files using gulp task when using glob?

I already checked this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546931/use-gulp-to-select-and-move-directories-and-their-files), but it moves to the root folder projects.