# Copy multiple specific files and folders to another directory using gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to copy multiple files and folders using `gulp.src` and `gulp.dest` from my base directory `.` to a new subdirectory `dist`.

The base directory is the root of a Symfony project.

Here's my gulpfile:

```
var files = [
  './app**/*.*',
  './bin**/*.*',
  './src**/*.*',
  './tests**/*.*',
  './var/',
  './vendor/',
  './composer.json']

gulp.task('distribute', function() {
  return gulp.src(files , { base: '.' }).pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

I just don't understand, why this isn't working. As result, I get a `dist` folder with the contents of the specified folders. So `app`, `bin`, `src` etc. are missing as root folders.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Moving the directories themselves

Based on [Use gulp to select and move directories and their files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21557049/1218980), use `./` for the `base` option and make sure the paths are correct:

```
var files = [
  './app/**/*.*',
  './bin/**/*.*',
  './src/**/*.*',
  './tests/**/*.*',
  './var/',
  './vendor/',
  './composer.json'
];

gulp.task('distribute', function() {
  return gulp.src(files , { base: './' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

## Moving the files within each directories

Don't use the `base` option and change your paths a little.

```
var files = [
  'app/**/*.*',
  'bin/**/*.*',
  'src/**/*.*',
  'tests/**/*.*',
  'var/',
  'vendor/',
  'composer.json'
];

gulp.task('distribute', function() {
    return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

## Flexible way to threat each directory as a task

If you want to move the folder themselves, just make a task for each one using a task generator function.

```
function moveDirTask(dir, dest) {
    return function() {
        return gulp.src(`${dir}/**/*`)
            .pipe(gulp.dest(`${dest}/${dir}/`));
    };
}

gulp.task('move-app', moveDirTask('app', 'dest'));
gulp.task('move-bin', moveDirTask('bin', 'dest'));
gulp.task('move-src', moveDirTask('src', 'dest'));
gulp.task('move-tests', moveDirTask('tests', 'dest'));
// etc.

gulp.task('distribute', [
    'move-app',
    'move-bin',
    'move-src',
    'move-tests'
    // etc.
], function() {
    return gulp.src('composer.json')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this copies the contents of the first 4 folders, but not the folders themselves. How can I archive this?

Comment: @KevinGlier I updated the answer to reflect your expected behaviour.

Comment: Is there no way to get it to work like the linux cp command? cp -r app src bin tests composer.json dist/ ?

Comment: @KevinGlier with the `base` set to `./`, is it working?

Comment: Thank you, "Moving the directories themselves" did it for me. I just changed the *.* in the paths to a single *, so that also the shell scripts within the bin folder get copied.

Comment: Gulp newbie here, I have followed official instructions [here](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start/#install-the-gulp-command-line-utility) and can successfully execute their first `default` example.  However when I replace contents of `gruntfile.js` with contents of your second code snippet (with relevant file names) and run `gulp` from the command line, I get `ReferenceError: gulp is not defined`.   Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  **Edit**: Oh, I had to add `var gulp = require('gulp'); ` in `gruntfile.js`

Comment: @user1063287 it looks like you're confusing grunt and gulp which are both similar libs, but they don't share the same API. Gulp won't work with the gruntfile directly, and you need to install gulp as a dependency as well.

Comment: apologies, it was a typo, i did mean to write `gulpfile.js` instead of `gruntfile.js`, sorry.