# How to ignore **/* in gulp.dest()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a gulp task named html-build.

```
gulp.task('html-build',function(){
    return gulp.src("dev/**/*.html")
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("prod/templates/"));
});
```

I want to go through all the html files in my dev's subfolders and dev's inner folders. But I have to copy all of them at a single place in prod/templates folder.

Right now, say if there is some file dev/home/views/home-section1.html. With current task, I get - prod/templates/home/views/home-section1.html. But I want - prod/templates/home-section1.html

How to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to use `gulp-flatten`, as mentioned in this answer:
[Flatten glob down to one directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153338/flatten-glob-down-to-one-directory)