# Moving html files using gulp script

Tags: gulp, build-automation

I've gulp v3.9.1. With directory structure like this [Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U680U.png) ('app' being the parent directory) I want to move all my "app/**/*.html" files to a common 'dist/html' folder.

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html');
    var changed = require('gulp-changed');
    gulp.task('compileHTML', function(){
        return gulp.src('app/**/*.{htm,html}')
          .pipe(changed('app/**/*.{htm,html}'))
          .pipe(minifyHTML())
          .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/html/'));
    });
```

I don't want the directory structure(like the one inside app) to be retained. I just need all the html (from different directories, obviously) in one place, i.e. 'dist/html' directly.
On running

```
    gulp compileHTML
```

on console, I see html files copied along with directories.
Kindly, provide suggestions for correction.

Comment: Duplicate of [Flatten glob down to one directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153338/flatten-glob-down-to-one-directory)

Comment: I tried using 'flatten' & 'glob' from the post earlier. The problem with the former is hierarchy of directories isn't uniform in my case, so I'm getting again 'folders' inside my 'dist/html'. 'glob' seems to be doing the job but it skipped some files without echoing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gulp-rename` to place all html in one folder:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('compileHTML', () => {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.{htm,html}')
        .pipe(changed('app/**/*.{htm,html}'))
        .pipe(minifyHTML())
        .pipe(rename({dirname: ''}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/html/'));
});
```